# Can't find ADO.NET Entity Model Browser Window in vs2010

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, entity-model

I want to update my ADO.NET Entities Framework Model from the database, but I cannot find the [Entity Model Browser Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738483.aspx). There is an example of how to update my model [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/entity-framework-the-cribsheet/), but I cannot find how to open the model browser. Could someone please tell me exactly how to open it using Visual Studio 2010?

I tried finding it through the view menu, and I do not get any valid options when right-clicking on the .edmx file.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter, but this is an MVC2 project and the .edmx file is under my 'Models' folder.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

First, open up the EDMX file.  Then, in main menu select View > Other Windows > Entity Data Model Browser (it usually opens in the same panel as Solution explorer).

Comment: Do you have to install something extra? from the default installation, it does not show up for me.

Comment: @Gerardo: How do you try to open the browser? It is available only when you are in EDMX designer.

Comment: In vs 2013, you can also right click on the edmx diagram, and select Model Browser.

Answer (score 20):

For me, the sequence was:

1. Double-click the .edmx file
2. Right click any white space in the opened diagram
3. Click Model Browser in the context menu that appears

Happy coding, all. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Double click the edmx file in the Solution Explorer to bring up the Designer. The Model Browser should appear.

In my workspace it shows up in the same tab grouping as the Solution Explorer.

Comment: This actually didn't work for me, I had to open it through View -> Other Windows -> Entity Data Model Browser.